# Start service from Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

If I start my `Service` from `Activity` it runs properly (by clicking button). However it does not work if I start it from `BrodcastReceiver`. What am I doing wrong? 
Here is my code of `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`

http://pastebin.com/hDDrhg0B

http://pastebin.com/ey7bnJSw

Here is my manifest file
http://pastebin.com/fUcM6Qse

Comment: please post your mainfest

Comment: have You registered receiver and service in Your manifest?

Comment: what issue you are facing when starting service from broadcast received? can you see in log is broadcast receiver ever getting called ?

Comment: @sunil I posted the manifest file

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela No, actually when it is started from BR it does not show anything in the logcat, however it does if I start it from activity by clicking at the button

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes I did

Comment: can you please post code of main activity of button click

Comment: @sunil it just contains startService() method

Comment: @sunil http://pastebin.com/kX2U2VXv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it, and it works:

```
public class BadgesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BadgesReceiver";

    public static final String BADGES_UPDATE_ACTION = BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME + ".action.UPDATE_BADGES";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent != null ? intent.getAction() : null;
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive action: " + action);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action) && action.equals(BADGES_UPDATE_ACTION)) {
            final Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            i.setAction(MyService.UPDATE_BADGES_ACTION);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is UPDATE_BADGES_ACTION? compiler says it cannot resolve it :(

Comment: It's the action, it's defined in the 3rd line: public static final String BADGES_UPDATE_ACTION = BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME + ".action.UPDATE_BADGES";